# QtCreator and version control basic set-up

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, qt-creator

OK, so I'm relatively new with Qt and have never used a version control system before. I'd like to try git or Mercurial or something. I downloaded both, but in each case I get "cannot create repository" or "The parameter is incorrect" or "Unable to execute 'git': Process failed to start: No such file or directory" whenever I try to create a new project and set a version control system.

Can someone point a just a basic tutorial of how to get started? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it up and running with this:

http://www.hackido.com/2010/01/installing-git-on-server-ubuntu-or.html